# AT+CIPSEND HTTP Post not sending data

Tags: http, express, post, arduino, at-command

I am trying to send data from my arduino via SIM900 in form of JSON to database. I am getting response SEND OK but no data is received .

Data is in a string formated as json with data for my database.

Here is relevent parts of my arduino program:

```
String data= "{\"a\": 1000, \"b\": 1000, \"c\": 1000, \"d\": 1000, \"e\": 1000, \"f\": 1000, \"g\": 1000, \"h\": 1000, \"i\": 1000}";

 client.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"myapp.herokuapp.com\",\"80\"");

  delay(4000);

client.println("AT+CIPSEND");

   delay(1000);

  client.print("POST /writedata HTTP/1.1\r\n");

  client.print("Host: adressofmyapi.com\r\n");

  client.print("Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n");

  client.print("Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n");

  client.println(data);

  client.print((char)26);
```

For comparison this is working header from postman:

POST /writedata HTTP/1.1
Host: adressofmyapi.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: token

{"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1,"d": 1,"e": 1,"f": 1,"g": 1, "h": 1,"i": 1}

On server side I have simple JavaScript Express application.

```
app.post('/writedata',jsonParser, function(req,res){

var post = req.body;

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO database SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
         res.end('It worked');
});

});
```

I am using Heroku for hosting Express app, logs for tries from Postman and Arduino are almost indentical.

POSTMAN log

**2018-04-15T21:00:29.603646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/writedata" host=myapp.herokuapp.com
 request_id=415342d6-5419-4381-867c-1c1e11020a33 fwd="00.00.000.000" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=900ms status=200 bytes=128 protocol=https
Arduino log
2018-04-15T21:16:33.178261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/writedata" host=myapp.herokuapp.com
 request_id=7091e0b5-209e-4c41-97a9-a1e4403556b9 fwd="11.111.111.11" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=73ms status=200 bytes=128 protocol=http**

Why does posting with POSTMAN works and mine doesn't?
Thanks, Tom.